# How do I create a table using huxtable to produce a LATEX pdf output with knitr?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to produce a table using the [huxtable](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/huxtable.html) package but I'm missing something :

First I tried the following code (which is the example in git):

```
<<test>>=
color_demo <- matrix('text', 7, 2)
rainbow <- c('red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'turquoise', 'violet')
color_demo <- as_hux(color_demo)                  %>% 
    set_text_color(rainbow)                     %>% # text rainbow goes down columns
    set_background_color(rainbow, byrow = TRUE) %>% # background color rainbow goes along rows
    set_all_borders(1)                          %>% 
    set_all_border_colors('white')               %>%
    print_latex()
@
```

Which produced the following output, the table content was escaped with a double `##` character.

[image: wrong1]

I've also tried to use the `asis` chunk option but then I obtain the following, so the test is probably no meant to be run with this option :

[image: wrong2]

Here is my reproducible code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{test for huxtable}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
<<load_libraries, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, results ="hide">>=
library(knitr) 
library(huxtable)
@
<<test>>=
color_demo <- matrix('text', 7, 2)
rainbow <- c('red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'turquoise', 'violet')
color_demo <- as_hux(color_demo)                  %>% 
    set_text_color(rainbow)                     %>% # text rainbow goes down columns
    set_background_color(rainbow, byrow = TRUE) %>% # background color rainbow goes along rows
    set_all_borders(1)                          %>% 
    set_all_border_colors('white')               %>%
    print_latex()
@
<<test2,results ="asis">>=
color_demo <- matrix('text', 7, 2)
rainbow <- c('red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'turquoise', 'violet')
color_demo <- as_hux(color_demo)                  %>% 
    set_text_color(rainbow)                     %>% # text rainbow goes down columns
    set_background_color(rainbow, byrow = TRUE) %>% # background color rainbow goes along rows
    set_all_borders(1)                          %>% 
    set_all_border_colors('white')               %>%
    print_latex()
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your "asis" version, in the PDF has your 2 colorful columns on the right, but a series of 5 upside down question marks interspersed with three hyphens to the left.  The log shows many  errors, starting with: ! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> ...textwidth }} \par \par \hhline 
                                                  {>{\arrayrulecolor [RGB]{2...
l.256 \end{tabularx}
                    
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.

Comment: @lawyeR Thank you, yes it's obviously not meant to be run with asis, but then how do you use it ? I'm probably missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the `huxtable` function `report_latex_dependencies`, you should find that this set of packages needs to be included in your preamble.

```
\usepackage{array}   
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

When I included them, your code produced exactly the colored box you want.